# Why does the output remain blank?

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

I'm following the book "Black Hat Python", the author creates a TCP proxy, but I can't seem to make it work.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
import sys
import socket
import threading


# this is a pretty hex dumping function directly taken from
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/142812-hex-dumper/

def hexdump(src, length=16):
    result = []
    digits = 4 if isinstance(src, str) else 2

    for i in range(0, len(src), length):
        s = src[i:i + length]
        hexa = b' '.join([b"%0*X" % (digits, ord(x)) for x in s])
        text = b''.join([x if 0x20 <= ord(x) < 0x7F else b'.' for x in s])
        result.append(
            b"%04X   %-*s   %s" % (i, length * (digits + 1), hexa, text))

    print(b'\n'.join(result))


def receive_from(connection):
    buffer = b''

    # We set a 2 second time-out. Depending on your target this may need
    # to be adjusted
    connection.settimeout(2)

    try:

        # keep reading into the buffer until there's no more data or we
        # time-out
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            buffer += data

    except TimeoutError:
        pass

    return buffer


# modify any requests destined for the remote host
def request_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    return buffer


# modify any responses destined for the local host
def response_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    return buffer


def proxy_handler(client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
    # connect to the remote host
    remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    remote_socket.connect((remote_host, remote_port))

    # receive data from the remote end if necessary
    if receive_first:
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
        hexdump(remote_buffer)

        # send it to our response handler
        remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)

        # if we have data to send to our local client send it
        if len(remote_buffer):
            print("[<==] Sending %d bytes to localhost." % len(remote_buffer))
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)

    # now let's loop and read from local, send to remote, send to local
    # rinse wash repeat
    while True:
        # read from local host
        local_buffer = receive_from(client_socket)

        if len(local_buffer):
            print("[==>] Received %d bytes from localhost." % len(local_buffer))
            hexdump(local_buffer)

            # send it to our request handler
            local_buffer = request_handler(local_buffer)

            # send off the data to the remote host
            remote_socket.send(local_buffer)
            print("[==>] Sent to remote.")

        # receive back the response
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)

        if len(remote_buffer):
            print("[<==] Received %d bytes from remote." % len(remote_buffer))
            hexdump(remote_buffer)

            # send to our response handler
            remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)

            # send the response to the local socket
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)

            print("[<==] Sent to localhost.")

        # if no more data on either side close the connections
        if not len(local_buffer) or not len(remote_buffer):
            client_socket.close()
            remote_socket.close()
            print("[*] No more data. Closing connections.")
            break


def server_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port,
                receive_first):
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        server.bind((local_host, local_port))
    except socket.error as exc:
        print("[!!] Failed to listen on %s:%d" % (local_host,
                                                  local_port))
        print("[!!] Check for other listening sockets or correct "
              "permissions.")
        print(f"[!!] Caught exception error: {exc}")
        sys.exit(0)

    print("[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (local_host, local_port))

    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()

        # print out the local connection information
        print("[==>] Received incoming connection from %s:%d" % (
            addr[0], addr[1]))

        # start a thread to talk to the remote host
        proxy_thread = threading.Thread(target=proxy_handler, args=(
            client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first))
        proxy_thread.start()


def main():
    # no fancy command line parsing here
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 5:
        print("Usage: ./proxy.py [localhost] [localport] [remotehost] "
              "[remoteport] [receive_first]")
        print("Example: ./proxy.py 127.0.0.1 9000 10.12.132.1 9000 True")
        sys.exit(0)

    # setup local listening parameters
    local_host = sys.argv[1]
    local_port = int(sys.argv[2])

    # setup remote target
    remote_host = sys.argv[3]
    remote_port = int(sys.argv[4])

    # this tells our proxy to connect and receive data
    # before sending to the remote host
    receive_first = sys.argv[5]

    if "True" in receive_first:
        receive_first = True
    else:
        receive_first = False

    # now spin up our listening socket
    server_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first)


main()
```

With the following command:

```
sudo ./proxy.py 127.0.0.1 21 ftp.target.ca 21 True
```

The program should give an output like this:

```
[*] Listening on 127.0.0.1:21
[==>] Received incoming connection from 127.0.0.1:59218
0000 32 32 30 20 50 72 6F 46 54 50 44 20 31 2E 33 2E 220 ProFTPD 1.3.
0010 33 61 20 53 65 72 76 65 72 20 28 44 65 62 69 61 3a Server (Debia
0020 6E 29 20 5B 3A 3A 66 66 66 66 3A 35 30 2E 35 37 n) [::ffff:22.22
0030 2E 31 36 38 2E 39 33 5D 0D 0A .22.22]..
[<==] Sending 58 bytes to localhost.
[==>] Received 12 bytes from localhost.
0000 55 53 45 52 20 74 65 73 74 79 0D 0A USER testy..
[==>] Sent to remote.
[<==] Received 33 bytes from remote.
0000 33 33 31 20 50 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 20 72 65 71 331 Password req
0010 75 69 72 65 64 20 66 6F 72 20 74 65 73 74 79 0D uired for testy.
0020 0A .
[<==] Sent to localhost.
[==>] Received 13 bytes from localhost.
0000 50 41 53 53 20 74 65 73 74 65 72 0D 0A PASS tester..
[==>] Sent to remote.
[*] No more data. Closing connections.
```

I've tried with different options, like using a different ftp server (e.g. ftp.dlptest.com) and even set up my own ftp server on a Windows 7 machine (same subnet), but I still can't get a connection.

(on a different terminal I can easily connect to the specified ftp servers using the command

```
ftp ftp.dlptest.com
```

)

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, "output remains blank" means that you run this script but it doesn't print anything at all, but just exits immediately?

Comment: I mean that it's stuck on "listening on...", it does not receive (?) incoming connections

Comment: you should run `ftp 127.0.0.1 21` to connect with your server. This gives me `[==>] Received incoming connection from 127.0.0.1:52776`. But it still need some changes

Comment: next problem - you have to use `socket.timeout` instead of `Timeout` to catch timeout

Comment: next problem - code doesn't need `ord()` because it gets bytes from server. It seems this code was created for `Python 2` and it needed `ord()` because it treated `bytes` like `str`

Comment: BTW: code may need bigger value in `connection.settimeout(2)` when it waits for data from client because human needs some time to put text in console - ie. login and password in FTP connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it with `127.0.0.1 21`

```
sudo ./proxy.py 127.0.0.1 21 ftp.dlptest.com 21 True
```

then you have to connect with this server using

```
ftp 127.0.0.1 21
```

and then it start working.

---

But there is different problem: it seems `hexdump` was created for Python 2 which treats `bytes` and `str` as the same type of data - and it uses `ord()` to convert char to its code/number. In Python 3 it is not needed.

You can also convert directly its code to string `chr(x)` and concatenate to string which you want to display.

```
def hexdump(src, length=16):
    result = []
    digits = 4 if isinstance(src, str) else 2

    #print('[DEBUG] src:', type(src))

    for i in range(0, len(src), length):
        s = src[i:i+length]

        data = ['%0*X' % (digits, x) for x in s]     
        #print('[DEBUG] data:', data)
        hexa = ' '.join(data)
        #print('[DEBUG] hexa:', hexa)
        
        data = [chr(x) if 0x20 <= x < 0x7F else '.' for x in s]
        #print('[DEBUG] data:', data)
        text = ''.join(data)
        #print('[DEBUG] text:', text)
        
        result.append(
            "%04X   %-*s   %s" % (i, length * (digits+1), hexa, text))

    print('\n'.join(result))
```

---

Other problem: it needs `socket.timeout` instead of `Timeout` to catch this exception.

---

Other problem: when code wait for local data then it may need bigger value in `connection.settimeout(2)` because human may need time to put some data - ie. login and password in FTP connection. I use different values for different connections. As default it uses 2 second

```
def receive_from(connection, timeout=2):

    connection.settimeout(timeout)
```

but for local data it uses 10 seconds

```
local_buffer = receive_from(client_socket, 10)
```

---

BTW:

I also catch `KeyboardInterrupt` so I can close connection when I stop server using `Ctrl+C`.

I also add

```
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

to resolve problem with error `[Errno 98] Address already in use` when server is started again.

---

Code:

```
import sys
import socket
import threading


# this is a pretty hex dumping function directly taken from
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/142812-hex-dumper/

def hexdump(src, length=16):
    result = []
    digits = 4 if isinstance(src, str) else 2

    #print('[DEBUG] src:', type(src))

    for i in range(0, len(src), length):
        s = src[i:i+length]

        data = ['%0*X' % (digits, x) for x in s]     
        #print('[DEBUG] data:', data)
        hexa = ' '.join(data)
        #print('[DEBUG] hexa:', hexa)
        
        data = [chr(x) if 0x20 <= x < 0x7F else '.' for x in s]
        #print('[DEBUG] data:', data)
        text = ''.join(data)
        #print('[DEBUG] text:', text)
        
        result.append(
            "%04X   %-*s   %s" % (i, length * (digits+1), hexa, text))

    print('\n'.join(result))


def receive_from(connection, timeout=2):
    buffer = b''

    # We set a 2 second time-out. Depending on your target this may need
    # to be adjusted
    connection.settimeout(timeout)

    try:

        # keep reading into the buffer until there's no more data or we
        # time-out
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            buffer += data

    except socket.timeout as ex:
        #print('TimeoutError:', ex)
        pass

    print('[DEBUG] buffer:')
    print(buffer.decode())
    
    return buffer


# modify any requests destined for the remote host
def request_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    return buffer


# modify any responses destined for the local host
def response_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    return buffer


def proxy_handler(client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
    print(client_socket)
    print(remote_host, remote_port)
    print(receive_first)
    
    # connect to the remote host
    remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    remote_socket.connect((remote_host, remote_port))

    # receive data from the remote end if necessary
    if receive_first:
        print('receive first')
        
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
        hexdump(remote_buffer)

        # send it to our response handler
        remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)

        # if we have data to send to our local client send it
        if len(remote_buffer):
            print("[<==] Sending %d bytes to localhost." % len(remote_buffer))
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)

    # now let's loop and read from local, send to remote, send to local
    # rinse wash repeat
    while True:
        # read from local host
        local_buffer = receive_from(client_socket, 10) # longer time for user response

        if len(local_buffer):
            print("[==>] Received %d bytes from localhost." % len(local_buffer))
            hexdump(local_buffer)

            # send it to our request handler
            local_buffer = request_handler(local_buffer)

            # send off the data to the remote host
            remote_socket.send(local_buffer)
            print("[==>] Sent to remote.")

        # receive back the response
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)

        if len(remote_buffer):
            print("[<==] Received %d bytes from remote." % len(remote_buffer))
            hexdump(remote_buffer)

            # send to our response handler
            remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)

            # send the response to the local socket
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)

            print("[<==] Sent to localhost.")

        # if no more data on either side close the connections
        if not len(local_buffer) or not len(remote_buffer):
            client_socket.close()
            remote_socket.close()
            print("[*] No more data. Closing connections.")
            break


def server_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port,
                receive_first):
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    try:
        server.bind((local_host, local_port))
    except socket.error as exc:
        print("[!!] Failed to listen on %s:%d" % (local_host,
                                                  local_port))
        print("[!!] Check for other listening sockets or correct "
              "permissions.")
        print(f"[!!] Caught exception error: {exc}")
        sys.exit(0)

    print("[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (local_host, local_port))

    server.listen(5)

    try:
        while True:
            client_socket, addr = server.accept()

            # print out the local connection information
            print("[==>] Received incoming connection from %s:%d" % (
                addr[0], addr[1]))

            # start a thread to talk to the remote host
            proxy_thread = threading.Thread(target=proxy_handler, args=(
                client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first))
            proxy_thread.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('KeyboardInterrupt')
        server.close()

def main():
    # no fancy command line parsing here
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 5:
        print("Usage: ./proxy.py [localhost] [localport] [remotehost] "
              "[remoteport] [receive_first]")
        print("Example: ./proxy.py 127.0.0.1 9000 10.12.132.1 9000 True")
        sys.exit(0)

    # setup local listening parameters
    local_host = sys.argv[1]
    local_port = int(sys.argv[2])

    # setup remote target
    remote_host = sys.argv[3]
    remote_port = int(sys.argv[4])

    # this tells our proxy to connect and receive data
    # before sending to the remote host
    receive_first = sys.argv[5]

    receive_first = ("True" in receive_first)

    # now spin up our listening socket
    server_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first)

main()
```

When I run in one console

```
 sudo python3.7 proxy.py 127.0.0.1 5005 ftp.dlptest.com 21 True
```

and in second

```
 ftp 127.0.0.1 5005
```

then I get

```
$ sudo python3.7 proxy.py 127.0.0.1 5005 ftp.dlptest.com 21 True

[*] Listening on 127.0.0.1:5005
[==>] Received incoming connection from 127.0.0.1:50124
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 5005), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 50124)>
ftp.dlptest.com 21
True
receive first
[DEBUG] buffer:
220-#########################################################
220-Please upload your web files to the public_html directory.
220-Note that letters are case sensitive.
220-#########################################################
220 This is a private system - No anonymous login

0000   32 32 30 2D 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23    220-############
0010   23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23    ################
0020   23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23    ################
0030   23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 0D 0A 32    #############..2
0040   32 30 2D 50 6C 65 61 73 65 20 75 70 6C 6F 61 64    20-Please upload
0050   20 79 6F 75 72 20 77 65 62 20 66 69 6C 65 73 20     your web files 
0060   74 6F 20 74 68 65 20 70 75 62 6C 69 63 5F 68 74    to the public_ht
0070   6D 6C 20 64 69 72 65 63 74 6F 72 79 2E 0D 0A 32    ml directory...2
0080   32 30 2D 4E 6F 74 65 20 74 68 61 74 20 6C 65 74    20-Note that let
0090   74 65 72 73 20 61 72 65 20 63 61 73 65 20 73 65    ters are case se
00A0   6E 73 69 74 69 76 65 2E 0D 0A 32 32 30 2D 23 23    nsitive...220-##
00B0   23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23    ################
00C0   23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23    ################
00D0   23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23    ################
00E0   23 23 23 23 23 23 23 0D 0A 32 32 30 20 54 68 69    #######..220 Thi
00F0   73 20 69 73 20 61 20 70 72 69 76 61 74 65 20 73    s is a private s
0100   79 73 74 65 6D 20 2D 20 4E 6F 20 61 6E 6F 6E 79    ystem - No anony
0110   6D 6F 75 73 20 6C 6F 67 69 6E 0D 0A                mous login..
[<==] Sending 284 bytes to localhost.
[DEBUG] buffer:
USER furas

[==>] Received 12 bytes from localhost.
0000   55 53 45 52 20 66 75 72 61 73 0D 0A                USER furas..
[==>] Sent to remote.
[DEBUG] buffer:
331 User furas OK. Password required

[<==] Received 38 bytes from remote.
0000   33 33 31 20 55 73 65 72 20 66 75 72 61 73 20 4F    331 User furas O
0010   4B 2E 20 50 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 20 72 65 71 75    K. Password requ
0020   69 72 65 64 0D 0A                                  ired..
[<==] Sent to localhost.
[DEBUG] buffer:
PASS adasdasda

[==>] Received 16 bytes from localhost.
0000   50 41 53 53 20 61 64 61 73 64 61 73 64 61 0D 0A    PASS adasdasda..
[==>] Sent to remote.
[DEBUG] buffer:

[*] No more data. Closing connections.
^CKeyboardInterrupt
```

and

```
$ ftp 127.0.0.1 5005

Connected to 127.0.0.1.
220-#########################################################
220-Please upload your web files to the public_html directory.
220-Note that letters are case sensitive.
220-#########################################################
220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
Name (127.0.0.1:furas): 
331 User furas OK. Password required
Password:
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
Login failed.
No control connection for command: Success
ftp> quit
```

---

**BTW:** if you use port bigger then `1024` (like `5005` in my answer) then it should run without `sudo`.

Comment: With your code I get the expected results, I need to study it throughly
Thank you, I really learned a lot